# Call a function from a string array (Java or Groovy)

Tags: java, reflection, groovy

In Java, or Groovy, say I have a String array like

```
myArray = ["SA1", "SA2", "SA3", "SA4"]
```

I want to call a different function based off of each string.

```
class Myclass{
  public static void SA1() {
    //doMyStuff
  }
  public static void SA2() {
    //doMyStuff
  }
  ...etc
}
```

I would love to be able to loop through my array and call the functions that they pertain to without having to compare the string or make a case statement. For example is there a way to do something like the following, I know it doesn't currently work:

```
Myclass[myArray[0]]();
```

Or if you have suggestions of another way I can structure something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In groovy you can do:

```
Myclass.(myArray[0])()
```

In Java you can do:

```
MyClass.class.getMethod(myArray[0]).invoke(null);
```

Comment: Hallelujah! I'm so glad I am using groovy. That's exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: And on your java example, what is the null for when you invoke the method?

Comment: Normally you want to execute methods on objects. In this case you have to pass the `object` you want to use. But in your example you are using static methods so no object is needed. Thats why null is passed to the `invoke` method.

Comment: @micha, why `println Myclass.(myArray[0])()` works but `myArray.each { println Myclass.(it)() }` doesn't?

Comment: Hm good question, I am not sure. `MyClass.(it.toString())()` works

Answer (score 4):

In Groovy, you can use a GString for dynamic method invocation:

```
myArray.each {
  println Myclass."$it"()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can, for instance, declare an interface such as:

```
public interface Processor
{
    void process(String arg);
}
```

then implement this interface, for example in singletons.

Then create a `Map<String, Processor>` where keys are your strings, values are implementations and, when invoking:

```
Processor p = theMap.containsKey(theString)
    ? theMap.get(theString)
    : defaultProcessor;

p.process(theString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at Reflection APIs, to call methods at runtime
check [Reflection docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)

```
Class cl = Class.forName("/* your class */");
Object obj = cl.newInstance();

//call each method from the loop
Method method = cl.getDeclaredMethod("/* methodName */", params);
method.invoke(obj, null);
```